# How to fix broken JQueryUI Datepicker

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui

I have a JQueryUI datepicker defined as follows:

```
$(function() {
  $(".visit_date").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
  });
});
```

The view code which produces the Datepicker text box is

```
<td><%= f.label :visit_date %></td>
<td><%= text_field_tag :visit_date, @visit.visit_date, :class => 'visit_date'
```

and the view, when rendered, is generated between tags like this:

```
<div id="action_window">
   (rendered HTML to be acted on by user) 
</div>
```

Why doesn't the Javascript selector ".visit_date" hook up with this view? In other words, without the "action_window" tags it used to work. My thinking was that ".visit_date" would match anything with class "visit_date".

======================
UPDATE on 11/7/2012. Javascript code:

```
$(function() {
  $("#visit_date").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
});
```

});

The original place where the user pushes the button:

```
<%= link_to "Add Visit", new_client_visit_path(@client), :remote => true, :class => "btn btn-primary btn-large" %>
```

In VisitsController:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.js { }
end
```

In views/visits/new.js.erb:

```
$('#action_window').html('<%= escape_javascript render(:partial => "new") %>');
$('#action_window').show;
```

(#action_window is a div in the Client index view)

In views/visits/_new.html.erb:

```
<%= render "form" %>
<%= link_to "Cancel", @client, :class => "btn btn-primary btn-large" %>
```

In views/visits/_form.html.erb:

```
%= form_for [@client, @visit] do |f| %>
<td><%= text_field_tag :visit_date, @visit.visit_date, :class => 'visit_date' %>
```

I have not been able to get the Datepicker to work, presumably because the HTML creating the "New Visit" view is rendered, and somehow JQueryUI can't associate it without that "hasDatepicker" thing added to the class.

Comment: That code worked for me, are you getting any javascript errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you dynamically add an element you want to be a date picker, and the original static page contains say this jquery to make some elements datepicker:

$('.visit_date').datepicker();

When the new element get's added, and it has class='visit_date',  it won't be a datepicker UNLESS you call jquery's datapicker on it.

So if you are using new.js.erb to add a dynamic datepicker element,  you could do this:

```
$('#action_window').html('<%= escape_javascript render(:partial => "new") %>');
$('.visit_date').datepicker();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your assumption about the class selector is correct. In my experience, datepicker should hook up to which ever class/id you select, regardless of what div contains it. I would check these things:

1. Make sure you don't have two jQuery  tags by mistake. I did that and date picker would not work.
2. Is there any javascript code before this code that is breaking? I think JS execution will halt whenever the first error is encountered. I would open the page in Chrome, Right click to Inspect Element, and view Console to see if there are any JS errors.

These suggestions are based on the assumption that your rails code is producing input tags with class="visit_date".

Comment: Well, this is very interesting, @rizalp1 and Cyle Hunter. Thanks for your comments. The rails code is definitely generating code with input tags of class "visit_date". And there are no Javascript errors. But somehow- I looked through some old threads - and JQuery UI somehow causes the class name to be "visit_date hasDatepicker". So if I render the HTML (Rails code) without that, somehow, JQueryUI doesn't know it is a datepicker. I haven't found a solution yet.

Comment: Maybe it's just a jquery syntax I'm un-aware of, but shouldn't the datepicker call be inside  a $(document).ready(function() { }?  Or is what you have a shorthand notation for the same thing?

Comment: Also,  is any of your stuff dynamically created via AJAX calls?

Comment: Hey @RadBrad, yes, the stuff is dynamically created (rendered) by AJAX. Somehow, in the use of datepicker, the class becomes "visit_date hasDatepicker" and I was not able to synch up the Javascript function and the dynamically generated HTML. (your recipe, in the other thread, led to the dynamic HTML generation)

Comment: when you return HTML from an AJAX call that introduces a new element that should be a data picker,  tack on the javascript that set's the element to be a date picker.  If you want further explanation, let me know and I'll post as an answer.

Comment: Hey @RadBrad, I tacked the current code up there, where it is still not recognizing the Datepicker. I couldn't figure out how to properly tack on the Javascript. Please post as an answer.